# How to add an Icon to an OpenERP custom developed module

Tags: odoo

In OpenERP Web 6.1 the modules Kanban view presents an icon for each of the apps.
How do you add a module icon to a custom developed module.
I have tried to add an image at `mymodule\static\src\img\icon.png`, but it looks like this is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in odoo v8 you can add icon in folder `addons/your_module/static/description/icon.png`

for example you can find icon for module employe
in `\openerp\addons\hr\static\description\`

Answer (score 2):

In the `__openerp__.py` file of your module add **'application':True** and then as you mentioned add the image (64x64 pixel) to yourmodule/static/ing/icon.png , Now Restart the server.

Comment: Still no success: __openerp__.py has `'application': True`; copied the icon from a standard module, guaranteeing 64x64 pixel size; restarted server; checked file permissions are ok; cleaned browser cache; tried with a different browser (IE); checked ir_module_module.icon database field has `/base/static/src/img/icon.png`, like standard modules. Looking at the page's html, the img tag is missing the src: `<img class="oe_module_icon" src="">`; but why?

Comment: I didn't solve my problem, but probably it is a very specific problem on my installation.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the same exercise in my local.

but its working fine @ my side.

You can Find where exactly the problem is by tracing the file: server/openerp/modules/module.py

There is a function

```
def get_module_icon(module):
```

if this function return the vealue like: yourmodule/static/src/img/icon.png
then its ok from your side.

Also run the "Update Module List" wizard.

plz take the latest revision of webclient.

hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

As of openERP 7.0, you can change the icon by editing your module's `__openerp__.py` file to have a key `icon` set to the path to your icon without having to follow much conventions, although it needs to be under `/static` directory.  As in:

```
{
  'name': 'Some Module Name',
  'icon': "/{my_module_name}/static/img/some_icon.png",
  ...
}
```

The path is like this because it will be used as the value of `<img>`'s `src=` attribute.

```
<img class="oe_module_icon" src="/{my_module_name}/static/img/some_icon.png">
```